# Array of objects: recommended to select specific item via objects key or Array Index or the Array item itself?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am dealing with an Array`[]` of Class Objects. The requirement is to use that array of objects to remember the currently selected object. For example, I have a class called `Person`, and `contacts` is the array of the `var obj = new Person(); contacts.push(obj);`

```js
class Person(){
   // props, constructors and methods 
}

const contacts = [new Person(0), new Person(1), new Person(2), new Person(3)]

var selectedPerson;
```

So I want the user to select any `person` from the `contact` list so I am using `<select>` and `<option>` for the user to allow selection of any `Person` This means I am using `name` props of the `Person` so I am getting `name` of the `Person` from the user selections now when a user selects or does anything that needs interaction with the `Person`'s object or using that doing few calculations for the user and shows the results.

I can use the `onChange` event on the `<select>`

```js
onChange(e){
   // store the value and filter it out to get the Person object when need calculation
   selectedPerson = e.target.value
   // store the contact item which is person object and use them everywhere
   selectedPerson = contacts.find((person)=> person.name===e.targe.value)
}
// multiple use of the selectedPerson
```

Which is the better way and why?

Is there any other way to achieve the same more efficiently?

Please share thoughts that are not asked properly on the question.

Comment: Personally I would go with retriving the Person object in its entirety.  Otherwise you're just assigning the selectedPerson varible to a name which you will probably later use to retrieve the entire Person object...might as well have selectedPerson equal the Person object from the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is fine provided `name` is unique in the array of `Person` objects and the array isn't truly massive (which it won't be if it's feeding into `option` elements). Using `name` rather than array index is also more robust if the array contents change.

You might consider using a `Map` instead of an array:

```
const contacts = new Map();
function addContact(person) {
    // If you want proactive notification of *replacing* a person, uncomment:
    // if (contacts.has(person.name)) {
    //     throw new Error(`contacts map already contains a person named ${person.name}`);
    // }
    contacts.set(person.name, person);
}
addContact(new Person(0));
addContact(new Person(1));
// ...
```

Then in `onChange`:

```
onChange(e) {
    const person = contacts.get(e.target.value);
    // ...
}
```

That's just a more efficient retrieval than an array scan (but it's not going to matter with the number of people you're going to present in `option` elements) and, to me, semantically a bit more of a fit for the operation — there's no chance of duplicated names. If you need to loop through the entries in the map (in the order they were added), maps are iterable:

```
for (const person of contacts.values()) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) class:

```js
const people = new Map()

people.set('Jane', new Person('Jane'))
people.set('John', new Person('John'))

people.has('Jane') // true
people.has('Jack') // false

console.log(people.get('Jane'))
```